# Convert javascript getElementsByName to Jquery

Tags: jquery

Could anyone please corret me with what I'm doing wrong on scenario below?

I've got bunch of `document.getElementById` statement which I would like to convert in to JQuery `each` loop. Some reason it's not working, please see my jquery below:

```
 $('.select').each(function () {
              $(this).addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
                  e.stopPropagation();
              }, false);

          });
```

In nustshell, i'm trying to attach `addEventListner` to all the `select` elements.

Comment: `$(this)` returns a jQuery object wrapping the DOM element bound to `this` in the callback. There is no method `addEventListener` on a jQuery object. Perhaps see `bind`? If the "touchstart" event is not supported in this case (`bind` only supports a subset of events), just use `this.addEventListener(...)` (no `$(...)`) as `this` refers to the DOM element itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are selecting elements with a class name of `select`.

Drop the `.` and it will select `select` elements.

Also, you can bind that event with jQuery without having to explicitly iterate over the set.

This is what it should look like...

```
$('select').bind('touchstart', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the period to just target `<select>` elements, keep it to target class="select"

Comment: the reason I put period is that i created class="select" as it select itself did not work. see alex's answer above, which works. The problem was $this.

Comment: that's cool, i mean he said the same thing... plus his answer is not using the class but the element... plus your question was `"In nustshell, i'm trying to attach addEventListner to all the select elements."` and not `"In nustshell, i'm trying to attach addEventListner to all the select elements with a class of select.`